# Multi-column file comparison and range extraction

Tags: perl

Pardon me for asking a question without any coding effort. But it seems too much difficult to me.

I have a data file with tab separated three data columns (and some repetitive header lines) as:

```
Sequence ../Output/yy\Programs\NP_416485.4 alignment. Using default output format...
# ../Output/Split_Seq/NP_415931.4.fasta -- js_divergence - window_size: 3 
# jjhgjg cstr score

0   0.89    u-p
1   -5.79   --- 
2   0.85    yui
3   0.51    uio
4   0.66    -08
Sequence ../Output/yy\Programs\YP_986467.7 alignment. Using default output format...
# ../Output/Split_Seq/YP_986467.7.fasta -- js_divergence - window_size: 3 
# jjhgjg cstr score

0   0.001   -s-
1   0.984   ---
2   0.564   -fg
3   0.897   -sr
```

From the second data column, for those value(s) which are more than 0.5, I want to extract the corresponding first column number (or range).

For the above Input, the output would be:

```
NP_416485.4: 1, 3-5
YP_986467.7: 2-4
```

Here, "NP_416485.4" and "YP_986467.7" are from header descriptor (after \Programs). (Note that, the actual value for "NP_416485.4" for example, should be, "NP_416485.4: 0, 2-4", but I increases all of them with +1 as I don't want to start with 0).

Thanks for your consideration. I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: perl -e 'undef $/;$content=<ARGV>;@list=split(/\n/,$content);for(@list){@fields=split(/\s+/);if(sprintf("%f",$fields[1])>0.5){print "$fields[0]\n";}}' file1

Comment: Gives these errors:

Comment: Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "]\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "??"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "}}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. In case you would have a DOS data file on a Unix machine, I used `\r?\n` to match a new line, so it will work for all cases:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = 'input.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $file_name ) or die "Could not open file '$file_name': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

my @chunks = $str =~ /(Sequence(?:.(?!Sequence))*)/sg;
my %ids;
for my $cstr ( @chunks ) {
    my ( $id, $data ) = $cstr 
        =~/Split_Seq\/(\S+)\.fasta.*?\r?\n\r?\n(.*)$/s;
    my @lines = split /\n/, $data;
    my @vals;
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        my @fields = split " ", $line;
        push ( @vals, $fields[0] + 1 ) if $fields[1] > 0.5;
    }
    $ids{$id} = \@vals;
}

for my $id ( keys %ids ) {
    my @tmp = sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $ids{$id} };
    my ( $first, $last );
    my @rr;
    for my $i (0..$#tmp) {
        if ( $i == 0 ) {
            $first = $tmp[0];
            $last = undef;
        }
        if ( $i < $#tmp && ($tmp[$i] == ($tmp[$i+1] - 1 )) ) {
            $last = $tmp[$i+1];
            next;
        }
        if ( defined $last ) {
            push @rr, "$first-$last";
            $last = undef;
        }
        else {
            push @rr, $tmp[$i];
        }
        $first = ( $i < $#tmp ) ? $tmp[$i+1] : undef;
    }
    say "$id: ", join ",", @rr;
}
```

**Output:**

```
NP_416485.4: 1,3-5
YP_986467.7: 2-4
```

Comment: brilliant.. it works on this dataset. but in larger files, it shows:        Use of uninitialized value $data in split at 3.pl line 15.
Use of uninitialized value $id in hash element at 3.pl line 21.
:

Comment: my large input file is in here: https://sites.google.com/site/iicbbioinformatics/share

Comment: Hmm.. seems like your large file has DOS line endings and also a slightly different format than the sample in your question

Comment: I now get: `ACY90833.1: 1-227` and `ACY90829.1: 2,4-5,7,10-66,68-146,151-201` for your real file. Is that correct?

Comment: in my machine, it shows: "Global symbol "$cstr" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $cstr"?) at 1.pl line 12."

Comment: Oops.. I pasted the line at the wrong place, sorry. I updated the answer, try now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give a good description of your problem, and you haven't made any effort to solve it yourself, but here's a solution to the first part of your problem (parsing the file into a data structure). You'll need to walk the `%results` hash and produce the output that you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;
my %results;
my $section;

while (<DATA>) {
  # Look for a new section
  if (/\\Programs\\(\S+)\s/) {
    $section = $1;
  }

  # Look for data lines
  if (/^\d\b/) {
     my @data = split;
     if ($data[1] > 0.5) {
       push @{$results{$section}}, $data[0] + 1;
     }
  }
}

say Dumper \%results;

__DATA__
Sequence ../Output/yy\Programs\NP_416485.4 alignment. Using default output format...
# ../Output/Split_Seq/NP_415931.4.fasta -- js_divergence - window_size: 3
# jjhgjg cstr score

0   0.89    u-p
1   -5.79   ---
2   0.85    yui
3   0.51    uio
4   0.66    -08
Sequence ../Output/yy\Programs\YP_986467.7 alignment. Using default output format...
# ../Output/Split_Seq/YP_986467.7.fasta -- js_divergence - window_size: 3
# jjhgjg cstr score

0   0.001   -s-
1   0.984   ---
2   0.564   -fg
3   0.897   -sr
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. But I am afraid that I have no idea of how to  covert these output values to ranges.. sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @J.Carter Then I guess you need to work out how to do that. Or hire a programmer..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help